# upgrade from wicket 1.4.9 to wicket 1.4.22 causes button to not be triggered

Tags: wicket, upgrade

We are using 1.4.9 for our current webapp. But we want to upgrade to higher 1.4.x version preferably 1.4.22(latest 1.4). The problem is that the page won't submit if AjaxButton is clicked. This is working in 1.4.9. I put breakpoint on the onSubmit of that button but it is not going there. Any insights on this? Thanks!

Here is the code:
For the button:

```
public abstract class SXIButton extends AjaxButton {
    public SXIButton(String id, Form form) {
    super(id, form);
    initialize();
    add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("validating", "false"));
}
}
```

In the java:

```
searchForm.add(new SXIButton("searchButton", searchForm) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -4366670520053224476L;

        @Override
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
            LOG.info("Searching Users");
            target.addComponent(userContainer);

            userSearchModel.setUserCurrentUserFilter(getSessionBOUser().getCd());
            UserDataProvider udp = new UserDataProvider(userSearchModel,isForSearch);
            udp.setSort("cd", true);
            userContainer.addOrReplace(getResultPanel(udp));
        }
    });
    add(portlet);
    portlet.add(searchForm);
```

in html

```
<input type = "submit" wicket:id = "searchButton" wicket:message="value:button.search" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Without any code it's hard to help you out. I would first check the [changelog](http://mirror.synyx.de/apache/wicket/1.4.22/CHANGELOG-1.4) to see if anything was changed in a later version that might causes you trouble (e.g. [this ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-1894)). If you cannot find anything obvious you might want to update first to another version which is not the latest one, to narrow down in which version your code breaks for the first time.

But those are just shots in the dark.